# optional argument value

Tags: c++

i want to create a function with an optional argument which take the value of another argument.
In the declaration of the function the following doesn't work, but this is exactly what i want to do :

```
void function(int a, int b=a)   //error
```

I try to set the default value of the variable b to the value of a.
What is the cleanest way to do that ? Can we do that without changing the signature of the function ?

Comment: is this a definition or a declaration (prototype or the implementation)?

Comment: Can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Write an additional function that takes just one argument and calls the original function:

```
inline void function(int a)
{
    function(a, a);
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you can explain why the original code in the OP was errorneous.

Comment: @Walter: without looking it up in the standard my guess would be that the default argument value has to be a compile-time constant.

Comment: @Walter It's just that function parameters cannot be used as default arguments.

Comment: @RalfSchallenberg: Not a compile time value. You can have a function call with diffenrent value: [Example](https://ideone.com/6sm2Ie)

Comment: @0x499602D2 Yes, I knew. I meant to suggest to Ralf to expand (and hence improve) the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Default argument must be `global variable` or `global constant`, even `function`. But it can not be `local variable`, because `local var` can not ensure in build.